# Locus of the points on complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, plane-curves, plane-geometry

We have a complex plane and there are inequality on it: $2|z| > |1 + z^2|$. What is the locus of such set of $z$?

I tried to solve it by using polar coordinates and got: $r^4 - 2r^2\cos(2\phi ) - 1 = 0$.

As well I tried solve it using $z = x + iy$ and got: $4(x^2 + y^2) = (x^2 - y^2 + 1)^2 + 4x^2y^2$

By I still can`t figure out what is the explicit name or at least descritpion for such locus of points. Will be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: squaring the inequality, using $\;|w|^2=w \bar w\;$ and regrouping:

$$
\begin{align}
4 z \bar z & \;\gt\; (1+z^2)(1+\bar z ^2) \\
z^2 + \bar z^2 - 2 z \bar z + z^2 \bar z^2 - 2 z \bar z + 1 & \;\lt\; 0 \\
(z-\bar z)^2 + (z \bar z - 1)^2 & \;\lt\; 0 \\
(z \bar z - 1)^2 - \left( i (z-\bar z)\right)^2 & \;\lt\; 0 \\
\left(z \bar z - 1 -i(z-\bar z)\right) \left(z \bar z - 1 + i(z-\bar z)\right) & \;\lt\; 0 \\
\left((z+i)(\bar z-i) - 2\right) \left((z-i)(\bar z +i)-2\right) & \;\lt\; 0 \\
\left(|z+i|^2 - 2\right) \left(|z-i|^2-2\right) & \;\lt\; 0
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

We are referring to a region outside the intersection, inside union of two separately defined circle boundaries A,B.

$$ A \cap B $$

$$ A: x^2 +(y+1)^2 =2,\, B: x^2 +(y-1)^2 =2\, $$

[image]

Comment: Why do we exclude intersection?

Comment: Just as a check take $z= 0+0i$ . We have $0>1$ which is inadmissible in this region.

Comment: Thanks a lot for attention.