# Complex plane region satisfying $|2z|>|1+z^2|$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am being asked to plot the geometric region on the complex plane for the following inequality.

$|2z|>|1+z^2|$

I wrote this as $|z-i||z+i|<2|z|$. I am not sure how continue from here. I thought about writing $z=a+bi$ and then calculate but it will involve $4$th powers and would be very long   and I am not sure even it will yield to solution.

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2149074/42969 – both found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%7C2z%7C%3E%7C1%2Bz%5E2%7C%24)

Comment: @MartinR Thanks.